# how to know which program uses key as keyshortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, guake

related to https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/316
F12 cannot be assigned as toggle guake terminal. How to know which program blocks it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Open "Keyboard" settings window and proceed to the shortcuts tab. Then select any unassigned shortcut and try to assign F12 to it. In the case of conflict you will be warned which command holds this shortcut.

Comment: Not if some program, like Guake, binds that key.

Comment: my problem is disappeared somehow , possibly, after reboot.